# Is it possible to batch-sell and move items?

Tags: grim-dawn

At the time I would like to pick up and sell all items "magical" (yellow) and above, but I have left a lot of loot behind because I find selling and moving objects one by one monotonous, more so when my inventory is filling and I have to leave an area prematurely. The same applies to the smuggler stash which is used to store items.

The optimal solution is an option sell or move all items of or below selected [rarity](http://www.grimdawn.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15748) at once, which I don't think is supported natively by the game.

Answer (score 2):

There is no in-game solution to batch sell. After some research there are no mods either to this day.

You can only set your drop quality filter to higher tier (e.g. rare+) and avoid lower items.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, will vote and accept after some research.